# Submit button with Requests is not allowed

Tags: python, authentication, button, python-requests, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to log into a page using Requests get/post, and it has given me problems.

I've pasted the html of the login form.

```
<form id="loginfrm" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="userid" name="username" autocomplete="off" placeholder="User Name" class="form-control" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="remember_forget">
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember_check" id="remember_me">
    <label for="remember_me">Remember me</label>
    <a href="/template/forgot-password.html" class="forget_password">Forgot Password?</a>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group last-form-group">
    <button id="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">LOGIN</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

First I don't know what action the button in the form has, since it doesn't have any 'action' nor 'a href' like the 'remember_forget' div.

Since I'm not sure how to submit the button (without using Selenium, because I want to iterate between some range), I decided to try using:

```
data = {'userid':'XXXXX', 'password':'YYYYY'} 
requests.post(html, data=data)
```

Also, not sure if I should use 'userid' or 'username' in this situation.

This has given me a 405 error, which I had not seen.

```
'405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.'
```

Is there someway of achieving this using Requests? If you have any suggestions I'd be happy to read up on it.

Thanks

Comment: It will be much easier if you'll catch request using sniffer or browser development tools and check actual data have been sent to server.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and found that you had to 'post' at another page; changing the 'www' (in this case it is 'cam') to 'api'. This gave me hope to think that they had an API however I couldn't find it.  So I tried the POST in the other link and got a Success. Now I want to access the original page or the data behind it.  PS. Is it ok to share the link?